# Uri from MediaScanner causes external Gallery to open incorrect video file

Tags: android, video, android-intent, android-gallery, android-mediascanner

I have an app that generates videos. After generating the video file, I'm using MediaScanner to get a Uri to the recently created video. Than I'm passing this Uri in an ACTION_VIEW intent. On some devices this works fine, but on others, subsequent activations with 2 different videos result in a mix - the 2nd ACTION_VIEW causes the Gallery app to play the 1st video again!

We also have a "share" option in the app that generates an ACTION_SEND intent with the same Uri. None of the recipients of this intent seem to repeat this wrong behavior.

This is how I activate the MediaScanner:

```
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] { path }, null,
    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
      public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        result = uri;
        scanFinished.signal();
      }
    });
```

This is how I create the view intent:

```
    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    viewIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
```

Thanks for any tip

Comment: did you `query(MediaStore.Video.Media#EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ...)`, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, I did. From the app, it seems totally correct. As if there is a cache outside of the process boundaries.

Comment: so if its correct, then you are most likely passing the wrong `Uri` to `setDataAndType`

Comment: I verified several times :-(

Comment: besides, I am passing the same Uri to the ACTION_SEND intent and I don't experience the same issue there, so I'm quite sure this is not the issue..